# Can someone tell me how to run Node.js on Unix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, unix

I downloaded version v0.8.9 onto a unix account  but I dont know how to run and test it... Theres no configure file and I cant find the directions online...

Comment: [You just need to scrolldown](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Why did I get minus two for this? What do you mean scrolldown? Where?

Comment: to [here](http://nodejs.org/#column1) if you haven't installed node look at me me me me's answer

Answer (score 3):

For some reason they make the source build dependencies and instructions difficult to find.

See this page: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

Prerequisites:

- GNU make 3.81 or newer. Pre-installed on most systems. Sometimes called gmake.
- python 2.6 or 2.7. The build tools distributed with Node run on python.
- libssl-dev (Node v0.6.x only.) Can usually be installed on *NIX systems with your favorite package manager. Pre-installed on OS X.
- libexecinfo (FreeBSD and OpenBSD only.) Required by V8. pkg_add -r libexecinfo installs it.

To install:

- tar -zxf node-v0.6.18.tar.gz *(Download this from nodejs.org)*
- cd node-v0.6.18
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install

Then you should be able to just type `node` to enter a REPL to do some basic testing. Otherwise search the web for books and tutorials.

Comment: Hey this doesnt work for me as I tried it earlier...I untarred the nodejs file and there is no ./configure file for me to run.  I cant find it in any of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I mistakenly downloaded the linux binary files and unpacked that.  You have to download the source code (tar.gz) file.  The binaries dont have the './configure' to run it.

Comment: that's because the binaries have a /bin folder with the node executable.

Comment: `./configure` doesn't run it, it configures the `Makefile` so you can compile it.